# Dashed line not distinguishable with thick Linewidth

Tags: octave

I would like to increase the Linewidth in my legend while also still being able to see that this line is dashed. I have a short sample of what I mean

```
for i=1:10
 x(i)=i;
 line1(i)=i;
 line2(i)=2*i;
endfor

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,line1,"-","LineWidth",1,x,line2,"--","LineWidth",1)
legend("solid","dashed")

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,line1,"-","LineWidth",10,x,line2,"--","LineWidth",10)
legend("solid","dashed")
```

This gives the following image
[image]

As you can see in the second picture there is only 1 line instead of a dashed line.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language but this seems like an issue where the length of the dash is so long that it renders as solid due to the limited size of the legend.

Comment: How would you expect that the legend is drawn? Increase the width of the legend box by a factor of approx. 4 so that the same lengths are usable? Perhaps you can add a hand-written sketch to show what output you've expected from your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment above has suggested, the dash is mimicking the properties of the line in the figure itself, and it is too long to be rendered in a way that is useful (in the context of your particular example, at least).

The legend is a proper axes object in itself, allowing you to get and set its properties. You can either increase its size and re-place the objects it contains in the appropriate positions, or, if you don't care particularly about the legend havind the same exact form as the plot itself, you could replace its linestyle or linewidth to something else. E.g. try adding the following lines after your example:

```
a = get(gcf, 'children');
b = get(a(1), 'children');
set(b(1), 'linestyle', ':');
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Andy's comment helped me come up with another approach compared to Tasos'. I increased the legend box size. There is still some need to play around with the definite position and size but it works as expected.

```
for i=1:10
  x(i)=i;
  line1(i)=i;
  line2(i)=2*i;
endfor

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,line1,"-","LineWidth",1,x,line2,"--","LineWidth",1)
legend("solid","dashed")

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,line1,"-","LineWidth",10,x,line2,"--","LineWidth",10)
hleg1=legend("solid","dashed")

%added line
set(hleg1,'position',[0.6 0.3 0.3 0.2])
```

[image]